# How do I stop content script execution in the current tab?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I'm working on a Google Chrome Extension, and I'm encountering a bug I can't solve on my own.

It works as expected switching to Youtube's Dark Mode on a single Youtube tab, but if you're on Youtube and *Ctrl/Cmd* click a link (open in a new tab), `content.js` is triggered again and the current tab is turned white and the new tab is dark.

If you are in a dark tab, a "child" tab should automatically be dark.

## manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "permissions": [
        "https://www.youtube.com/*",
        "activeTab"
    ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistant": false
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Engage Youtube Dark Mode."
    },

    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }]
}
```

## background.js:

```
//var alreadyTriggered = false;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "clicker.js"});
});
/*
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    alreadyTriggered = false;
});*/

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse) {
    //if (!alreadyTriggered) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "clicker.js"});
        //alreadyTriggered = true;
    //};
    return true;
});
```

## content.js:

```
var myDate = new Date();

if ((myDate.getHours() <= 7) || (myDate.getHours() >= 19))
{
    var darkMode = document.body.getAttribute("dark");
    if (!darkMode) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(window.location.href, function(result) {});
    };
};
```

I'm guessing that I'm using `activeTab` incorrectly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

## clicker.js:

```
stepOne();

function stepOne() {
    try {
        var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button.ytd-topbar-menu-button-renderer");
        buttons[0].click();
        stepTwo();
    }
    catch(error) {
        setTimeout(stepOne, 250);
    }
}

function stepTwo() {
    try {
        buttons = document.querySelectorAll("paper-item.ytd-account-settings");
        buttons[0].click();
        stepThree();
    }
    catch(error) {
        setTimeout(stepTwo, 100);
    }
}

function stepThree() {
    try {
        buttons = document.querySelectorAll("paper-toggle-button.style-scope.ytd-account-settings");
        buttons[0].click();

        document.body.click();
    }
    catch(error) {
        setTimeout(stepThree, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the comment. I just updated it to add the content.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ended up working for me was to use a combination of:
using `window.onload = doStuff();`

And to make sure that the value for `darkMode` was `null`, not `undefined`.

Hopefully this helps someone who's been endlessly tweaking their code.